# How to get words starting and ending with ^

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex

I have this string:

"lorem ipsum this is ^some text to use^ for example"

how can i getting only the words that starts and ends with ^?

so the result should be: "some text to use"

using c# regex or any other way.

Comment: What did you try? what did not work. You have to show that you attempted something at least before asking

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? We can simply give you answers, and you will likely get one, but it is best if you show any effort you have put into it and let members guide you to the correct answer by correcting any mistakes you have made.

Comment: You Can use Split And take the 2nd index No need For Regex

Answer (score 2):

```
Regex.Match(s, @"\^.+\^").Value
```

will give you : **^some text to use^**

```
Regex.Match(s, @"\^(.+)\^").Groups[1]
```

will give you : **some text to use**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\^\K\b[^\^]+
```

[Here is Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ULKyh2/3)

```
Regex.Match(myString, @"\^\K\b[^\^]+").Value;
```

**= "some text to use"**

If you have one match - you dont need groups. If you more then one - you have to use groups.

Answer (score 0):

This way is better than Regex.
String class is giving you ways to get what you want.
Plus there is no need to pollute the Code with Patterns

Try this one:

```
    string text= "lorem ipsum this is ^some text to use^ for example";

    var selectedtext = (text.Split('^')[1]);
```

Comment: That depends on the definition of "better" and would probably need some benchmarking as evidence. But yes, this is most likely the most simple solution.

Comment: its has its down sides though he should check the length of the array and handle many cases in order not to get an exception

Comment: and for me there absolutely no need to import the  Regex Name Space.

Comment: It isn't mentioned in the question, but it might be relevant. If there is a need to capture multiple pattern matches, this fails as it would only get the first one. It could also incorrectly get the second half of a text where, for some reason only one '^' existed. Whereas regex would ignore unless exactly matching.

Comment: the character '^' might change over time and he can handle the edge cases in order to make a reusable piece of code

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
(?<=\^\s*).+(?=\s*\^)
```

**This will give you result like, excluding ^ symbol**

```
some text to use
```

> If this help's don't forget to up vote.